# How should I adjust the time and/or temperature when baking a pound cake in loaf pans

Tags: baking, cooking-time

When splitting pound cake batter into two loaf pans instead of using a tube pan, how would you adjust your baking time and temperature?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn’t change much if anything.

The main factor for baking is volume and the area of the cross-section, or, in other words, how long does it take for the oven heat to reach the center parts of the batter and bake them. Under that premise, you could say a bundt pan is like a curved loaf pan, thanks to the chimney in the middle. But: The material of the pans will also be a factor in baking time, even if you are using the same shape, so a tiny bit of experimentation is called for here

So the recommendation is to treat your tried-and-tested recipe like a new one: Set your timer for about five to ten minutes less than you normally would, check the cake for doneness (thermometer or skewer that comes out clean) and if needed, continue baking until the cake is done. Tip: note the baking time for all pans that you used, this will be helpful next time.

Assuming that you are baking the pound cake at a relatively low temperature (160-175 C or 325-350 F), a few minutes deviation won’t cause it to burn.

Answer (score 0):

I've done just the opposite. The recipe directions called for baking a cake to be baked in a loaf pan and I switched to a tube pan with very little, if any noticable time change needed

As all cake recipes bake times are approximate, I always check doneness with a skewer/cake tester as the specified time nears completion

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the answer above re volume.  I substituted a loaf pan for a Bundt pan to bake a wet, Italian lemon Ciambellone, 2/3 cup oil, 1/2 cup milk, 4 eggs, vanilla, Tbl Lemoncello liquor.  Recipe called for 40-50 min at 350.  In a loaf pan, it went 20 min longer until toothpick check for done.  Thicker cross section cake took longer to bake.